# Problemas con .htaccess en servidor godaddy

Tags: php, .htaccess, godaddy, localhost

El problema es el siguente :

tengo un webservice  en el cual redirecciono todas las peticiones al `index.php` con un `.htaccess`

el codigo del `.htaccess`   lo dejare por aqui

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Cuando accedo a la url por ejemplo

```
http://localhost/app_restaurantes/restaurantes
```

(el directorio **restaurantes** no existe debe ser redireccionado al **index** para que  responda un json con la lista de restaurantes) el servicie trabaja perfectamente en localhost

Pero cuando subo el webservice al servidor de `godaddy.com` y accedo a una ruta me  muestra el siguiente error

> 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.

me imagino que el `.htaccess`  no esta trabajando

alguien sabe si el `htaccess` trabaja con una version especifica de apache o si debo hacer algun cambio en el `htaccess` ?

Comment: ¿Preguntaste ya a godaddy si tienen activada la reescritura de url??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Bueno La razon por la que el `htaccess`  no funcionaba es poque que mi servidor de godaddy es windows  es decir una mescla rara entre IIS y Apache 
lo probé en un servidor solo apache y funciona